# Why am I having so much trouble with this:

Tags: php, arrays, include

Please, Why am I having so much trouble with this, ($menu is an associative array). It is not looping:

```
<?php

foreach ($menu as $menuItem => $page) {

    if (isset($_GET[''])) {
        include PAGE_PATH . "/home";
    } elseif (isset($_GET['$menuItem'])) {
        include(PAGE_PATH . "/" . "$page");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: the title needs to be specific. What you have now, a Google search would probably find a lot of similar questions.

Comment: Enable error reporting. This though `$_GET['']` could be anything; your question is unclear as to what the rest of your code is.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expect with `$_GET['']`, but I doubt that is does what you expect.  Flip the logic and check for real get parameters. Also, variables are not parsed inside of single quotes `'` use double `"` or for array indexes just use the variable:

```
$include = "home";

foreach ($menu as $menuItem => $page) {
    if (isset($_GET[$menuItem])) {
        $include = "$page";
        // if multiple get params this will use first, remove to use last
        break;
    }
}
include(PAGE_PATH . "/$include.php"); // added .php
```

This is assuming that `$menu` looks something like:

```
Array
(
    [contact] => contact.php
    [about] => about.php
)
```

And the URL to access this page is something like: `index.php?contact` or `index.php?var=1&contact` etc.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a million AbraCadaver. You're spot on. Your understanding of my URL and the $menu array was accurate. Again Thanks